# Debian, XFCE & no Wallpaper

Tags: debian, xfce, wallpaper

I have a folder with pictures which I used as wallpapers for years on my debian 10.8 notebook. I'm using XFCE 4.12.5. Since some month I only have a gray background. The only thing I have changed was connectig a second disply to the notebook.
Having no wallpaper on XFCE has been asked here several times, but none of the solutions worked for me.
Going to the desktop settings, trying to set a pic as wallpaper via Thunar, ... nothing workend.

Comment: [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewforum.php?id=4) is a good place to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to list the settings in `xfce4-desktop` channel:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -lv
```

E,g; To set a wallpaper (it depend in the above output):

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop \
-p /backdrop/screen0/monitoreDP-1/workspace0/last-image \
-s /Path/to/wallpaper
```

Comment: root@grif:/home/me# xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -lv
    Fehler beim Initialisieren von libxfconf: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken..
root@grif:/home/me

Comment: Is there no one who has this problem also?